# How to instantiate a class based on a variable type of the class to be instantiated

Tags: c#, class, type-conversion, instantiation, converters

Is there a way to do instantiate a class,  **but not by it's classname**, but using the Class' type?
Possibly/probably using  Convert or reflection.?

e.g.  I have a class and typically create an instance of it as per..

```
TCustDataDetailModel newDataDetail = new TCustDataDetailModel ();
```

but  I want to be able to do it like ..

```
public void MyFunction (Type somePassedinParamType)
{
    somePassedinParamType newDataDetail  = new somePassedinParamType();

}
```

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Activator` class.

```
public void MyFunction (Type somePassedinParamType)
{
    var newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(somePassedinParamType);    
}
```

Note that is you do not have an empty constructor you will need to use one of the override of `CreateInstance` and pass what the class needs.